# Linux + AD + mount = problems writing files

Tags: linux, ssh, permissions, mount, active-directory

I have 2 Linux servers + 1 Active Directory There's a NFS disk mounted from the Linux 2 to Linux 1.

Users can access and write files from their Windows session on directories of Linux 1, and on directories of Linux 2 through the Linux 1 mounted disk.

Users can login with SSH using their AD account, they can write files in their home directory.

Problem is, in SSH they can't write into the mounted disk, although they belong to the appropriate group.

```
anthony.rodriguez@naboo:/var$ ll
total 56
drwxr-xr-x 14 root root     4096 sept. 17 13:58 ./
drwxr-xr-x 24 root root     4096 sept. 17 16:32 ../
drwxrwxr-x 52 root www-data 4096 sept. 21 15:18 www/

anthony.rodriguez@naboo:/var/www$ touch test2
touch: impossible de faire un touch «test2»: Permission non accordée
```

message says :

> Permission denied

When I check the groups :

```
anthony.rodriguez@naboo:/var/www$ groups
utilisateurs du domaine www-data BUILTIN\users grp_si
```

I tried the same on another directory (a local one), and it worked just fine.